# React-Native | Measured the inner width of ScrollView

Tags: android, react-native, scrollview

I've got horizontal `ScrollView`, and I'd like to measured the inner width and to scroll to the center of the component.

I know how to get the outer width (and how to use `.scrollTo()` function), but since the `ScrollView` had flexible width - I can't just use simple calculation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to `onContentSizeChange` events. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#oncontentsizechange

other option is to dig into internals of ScrollView - I used it once but there is no guarantee that it won't change with RN version.